# How to pass data to js-file via $getScript and how to access this data in this called js-file?

Tags: jquery

How can I pass a variable via `$getScript()` to the called js-file here `bfile.js`.

```
var x = new Array();
$.getScript('bfile.js', x);
```

I called it normally because I read that in the new called javascript file all variables are visible but for the variable `x`, I get a *Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined*.
Please help!

Comment: This will depend on how does the script expects the variable. If it is a global variable you could simply define it before calling the .getScript method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need to pass variables. just declare the variable as global variable before load the script. then it will available for any script load after that.